# Python to find words in a log, and save the lines that contain the strings in an output file with enumered lines and with space between them

Tags: python-2.7, with-statement, os.walk

This script's purpose is to search the log file of an msbuild, find the lines that contain the words "msbuild", "sln", "vcproj", and save the those lines in a new file enumered and with a space between them. I am really new in Python so I apologize for any silly mistakes

## !/usr/bin/python

```
import re
input_file = r"/path/build.log"
phrases = ("msbuild", "sln", "vcproj")
count = 1

with open(input_file) as file:
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in file:
            if any(s in line for s in phrases):
           
                count+=1
                print("\n")
                output_file.write(str(count)+'\t'+ line)
file.close()
    #output_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi Theo, would you be able to elaborate a bit on what your question is? You've posted some code, and the title gives a description of what you want, but what exactly isn't working? What's the output of your current code, and could you please give some input examples? Please also format your code as code, otherwise it's hard to read.

Comment: @Harry this is more detailed, I hope it makes more sense than the last time

Comment: Thanks for updating your post @Theo, but I am still unclear on what question you are asking. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, and while you've posted some code and a description, it's not clear what the problem with your code is, if any. As far as I can tell your code should work, although I could suggest some possible improvements. What is the question you wish to have answered? There's useful information on asking best practices here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask